# How do I get back to where I was before after hitting gg in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

For example, let's say I am happily editing a document in Vim when I accidentally hit gg. I then end up on the first row of the document, and of course I have no idea which was the exact row that I last edited. Is there any way of magically get back to the last edited row before the gg jump?

Comment: Great question that I'd just never thought to ask.

Comment: Tell me about it. I have used Vim for a few months now and the involuntary gg jumps have been pretty much my only 'bad' experience with Vim. But still I never figured out how to reverse it. Until today that is when I reached the tipping point and spent a few seconds here to get an answer!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The shortcut is `Ctrl+O` (that's the letter 'O') to move back to previous position.

And `Ctrl+I` to undo that (move back to the position before you pressed `Ctrl+O`).

These can be used multiple times like the back and forward buttons on your browser to travel to previously "jumped to" positions.

Comment: Superb. You have no idea how much profanity you have saved me from uttering.

Comment: @c00kiemonster - that's vim for you ;)

Comment: It evens works when you are jumping on a tag. I used to use Ctrl+T, now I use Ctrl+O/I all the way !

Comment: Good to know! I usually just use `'.` to go back to the last edit.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a mnemonic for `Ctrl-O` or is `O` just random?

Answer (score 10):

To bounce back and forth between your current position and the last place you jumped from, you can use ``` `` ``` (two backticks).  See ``` :h `` ``` for a list of this and other shortcuts for jumping around.

Comment: Backticks instead of Ctrl-because the backticks jump once, since the shortcut ctrol it takes us more deeply to the list of jumps